# How to stop Apify from saving handled requests?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, apify

It seems Apify is saving handled requests in 'handled' directory. I want to stop this because apify won't crawl the page I've crawled before. Anyone know how to stop Apify from saving handled request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this by putting the request in queue multiple times with a different [uniqueKey](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/request-options#uniquekey) so that it is not automatically filtered out by request queue after already having been processed once. Local files only simulate the behavior of [RequestQueue](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/request-queue#docsNav) exactly as it behaves on the Apify platform.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Apify CLI. Just start the run with `apify run -p`. `-p` means it purges the old request queue.